# is it possible to connect Openfire via http request?

Tags: server, openfire

suppose now I have an openfire XMPP server, 10 android tablab is connected to it and it is able to communicate to each other via openfire server.
and now there is another server from third party call Server A. Is it possible to let Server A to send some http request to openfire server to config the setting? such as create a chat room, delete a chat room and so on.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

yes you can create chat rooms over HTTP Request with help of Openfire MUC Service plugin.
You can download the plugin here: http://www.igniterealtime.org/projects/openfire/plugins.jsp
The full documentation for the REST interface is here: https://www.igniterealtime.org/projects/openfire/plugins/mucservice/readme.html

e.g. to create a chat room:

> Header: Authorization: Basic YWRtaW46MTIzNDU= Header: Content-Type:
>   application/xml
>
> POST http://example.org:9090/plugins/mucservice/chatrooms

Payload Example 1 (required parameters):

```
<chatRoom>
    <naturalName>global-1</naturalName>
    <roomName>global</roomName>
    <description>Global Chat Room</description>
</chatRoom>
```

If you need to create users over HTTP Request, you could use the User Service Plugin.

Comment: Thanks, one more question.
Can I make my own plugin to do so instead of using the existing User Service Plugin? as few more action I wanna do with the HTTP Request, such as, calling a custom function in openfire server.

Comment: Sure, you can implement you own plugin for openfire.
Guide for development: http://www.igniterealtime.org/builds/openfire/docs/latest/documentation/plugin-dev-guide.html
Also look at the current implementation of Openfire Plugins on github: https://github.com/igniterealtime/Openfire/tree/master/src/plugins